# how to add firstvalue by default null in spinner.?

Tags: android, json, spinner

I get the list data from webservices (Json) in spinner. But before websevices data in spinner i want show null value.(Need first value is null)

please any one help me.. 
please give me a sample code.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a dummy object representing your null value. But spinners are not designed for this - they should contain some data (or nothing if no data is available).

So in your case I would recommend using a `ListView` or something similar instead which could be opened in a new activity with `startActivityForResult` and return an `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing whole process with single thread?

you can use your listener, first you inflate empty array/list and later you can set your data change..

Answer (score 0):

A  null value inside a spinner will give you a really annoying exception. It's better to add as first element of the array some object like "Please, select one" or "Nothing selected". When you create the array you give to the spinner, first add this element and then load the real data.